# How do you compile multiple Swift files together, without using Xcode?

Tags: command-line, swift

I'm interested in Swift programming, but I'd prefer not to use Xcode as it is too bloated for my practical use.

I know this is possible to do with Objective-C with something like

```
 clang -fobjc-arc main.m myclass.m -o prog1
```

where the different .m files are just listed out, but I don't know how to do this with Swift. I can use the basic Swift command-line tool, like `swift MyProgram.swift` which just produces a binary called MyProgram.

As far as I can tell, this command won't let you compile multiple .swift files together.

Ideally, a system like makefiles for C++ would be ideal. Is there any way to do this with Swift currently from the command line?

Comment: Have you tried `swift File1.swift File2.swift main.swift` ?

Comment: Thank you! I feel silly now. I haven't been able to find and documentation (despite my best efforts) on the Swift command, so I was unaware. Do you know where I could find more information on it? @MartinR

Comment: Try invoking `swift --help`.

Comment: @MartinR I doesn't work anymore.
You need to use swiftc instead
`swiftc file.swift main.swift`

Comment: @KostiantynKoval: Yes, that changed some time ago.

Answer (score 0):

While you can use `swiftc`, the recommended way after Swift 2.1 is open-sourced is to use `swift build` as described at [Swift Package Manager documentation](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager).

An important note from that document:

> Please note, that the 2.2 release snapshot does not come with
>   swift-build-tool, either download the development snapshot or build
>   your own copy of swift-llbuild.

By developer snapshot they mean a developer snapshot installer from the [official package](https://swift.org/download/) or anything that's newer than Swift 2.2 at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend `swift build` for convenience, if however you want to do it by hand still, then run `swift build -v` and you will see the commands that are run by `swift build` so you can construct your own command lines.